# PHP post to another webpage and get response

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, html

I would like to make a script using PHP (probably need JS) to send POST data to another webpage from my webpage and get the result back from the website called.

For example, Domain A will have a form with a textbox and submit button(i.e. mywebpage), and Domain B will have a script which will fill the textbox and press the submit button and return the generated HTML page.

The website i want to execute the form is
http://esuvidha.info/ or http://esuvidha.info/rtURes/ResMainpage.php

Answer (score 0):

you must use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

i do like this work

```
function PostRequest($Url,$Fields,$Headers=array()) 
{
    $Curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_URL,$Url);
    curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $Fields);
    curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();
    $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
    session_write_close();   
    curl_setopt( $Curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie ); 
    if(isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']))curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE,"PHPSESSID=".$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
    $result=curl_exec ($Curl);

    curl_close ($Curl);
    return trim($result);
}
```

Comment: i am not so good in curl and programming can anyone is here for provide me help

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the CURL for this ,  and you need not to concentrate on page with text box and submit , instead of action of that form because you need to submit data from your webpage to other webpage form action.